# Federated Queue is not appearing in Downstream node/server

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-federation

I am trying to federate messages using Federate queue in two machines.But I am not able to see federated queue automatically creating in downstream server.
  Lets say example,I have two server A(Upstream) and B(Downstream).I did configuration properly and installed federation plugin and used policy ,

```
  rabbitmqctl set_policy --apply-to queues federate-me "" \ '{"federation-upstream-set":"all"}'
```

and added upstream ,

```
rabbitmqctl set_parameter federation-upstream my-upstream '{"uri":"amqp://****:****@address","expires":3600000}'
```

After that I have published one message to Queue("Test_Queue") to A server but the "Test_Queue" should automatically create in B Server right? but it is not happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.